# python PUT request 405 error No resource method found for PUT

Tags: python, python-requests, put, http-status-code-405

I did first search through all the similar 405 error posts I found but did not find one with an answer.

What is different here, is that the PUT only fails from Python requests, so I am really confused. Maybe someone has an idea of what might be going on ???

The same exact call, to POST works from Python.
The copied/pasted payload from Python, into POSTMAN works also.
The same payload copied/pasted as a PUT or POST works from POSTMAN.

I am using Python 2.7 on Win7

the full reponse from the request is:

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): {{fakeservername_replaced_for_stackoverflow_post}}
No resource method found for PUT, return 405 with Allow header
javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: No resource method found for PUT, return 405 with Allow header
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:375)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:114)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootNode.match(RootNode.java:43)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:444)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:234)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1651)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:176)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1631)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Finished: errors=1
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"PUT /api/v1/observations HTTP/1.1" 500 3078
```

The Python code is: *[with some extraneous debug/prints]*

```
def putData(_wqxobj, _interface ):
    global errors

    uri = url + u'/api/v1/%s' %_interface
    hdrs = {'Authorization': 'token ' + authToken, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    payload = _wqxobj    
    print '#======================= PAYLOAD =========================== #'
    print payload
    print '#==================== ENDPAYLOAD =========================== #'

    try:
        req = requests.put(uri, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=hdrs)              
        response = req.text
        print response

        if (response == 'Token is invalid.'):
            print 'error : ' + response

        if "gaia.domain.exceptions.NotUniqueException" in response:
            return "%s is not unique!"  %_interface
        else:    
            rj = req.json()
            print rj    

            _id = rj['id']

            return _id
    except Exception, e:
        errors += 1
        #print e
        err = str(e)
        return err
```

For reference, the payload, as passed in the code shown, copied and pasted into POSTMAN does work as a PUT:

```
{
'medium': 'WATER', 
'observedTime': '2014-08-20T10:00:00.000-00:00', 
'samplingLocation': {'id': '1f2df33e-790c-4065-bf90-ddf12a764039'}, 
'dataClassification': 'SENSOR', 
'resultTime': '2014-08-20T10:00:00.000-00:00', 
'observedProperty': {'id': '8effe050-c13f-4b57-9671-225523aeca77'}, 
'customId': 'observation_test_1'
}
```

Comment: Try comparing your request from Python and from Postman by targeting http://httpbin.org/put

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you can provide us with the information that @Wiwiweb asked for.